# How to use existing wamp's MySQL databases in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I already have WAMP server installed on my machine. Can I be able to access MySQL databases created on WAMP's MySQL using node-mysql module?

Actually, I tried this code, its running without errors but unable to fetch the database(or tables):

```
var http = require('http'), 
    mysql = require("mysql"); 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "database_name"
}); 

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on('end', function () { 
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM table_name', function (error, rows, fields) {            
            console.log('The first field is: ', rows[0].field);
        });
    }); 
}).listen(8001);

console.log("running on localhost:8001");
```

Comment: You don't need any code related to `http = require('http')` to test mysql connection. Also you should print error if any. Add `console.log(error)` to your query callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `request.resume();` before your 'end' event handler.

In node v0.10+, streams start out in a "paused" state that allow you to `.read()` specific sized chunks or you can use them like the old streams by attaching a 'data' event handler which causes the stream to be continuously read from.

Calling `request.resume();` will also switch to the old stream mode, effectively discarding the request data (because there are no 'data' event handlers) so that your 'end' event handler will be called.